# How do I register a ScalarDiscriminatorConvention for a different field name in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm writing C# code to pull data out of an existing MongoDB database and put it into various C# classes. One part of the database is polymorphic: if the field `type` is A, then a certain set of fields will exist in that document. If `type` is B, a different set of fields will exist. That's the perfect use case for `ScalarDiscriminatorConvention`, so I'm using `ScalarDiscriminatorConvention("type")`. But I don't know how to make the MongoDB driver use that convention!

[The MongoDB manual page on conventions](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/) made me think that this would work:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
pack.Add(new ScalarDiscriminatorConvention("type"));

ConventionRegistry.Register(
    "My Custom Conventions",
    pack,
    t => t.FullName.StartsWith("MyNamespace."));
```

But this fails because `ScalarDiscriminatorConvention` doesn't derive from the `IConvention` interface like the other conventions do. It derives from `IDiscriminatorConvention`, which is its own interface that does not derive from `IConvention`. And `ConventionPack.Add` expects an `IConvention` parameter.

So how do I register a different discriminator field? I've hunted through the MongoDB manual for at least an hour now and I'm quite at a loss. They don't seem to have it documented anywhere that I could find.

Comment: The docs are here: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/.  However, it appears this isn't documented... I'll find some more info.

Comment: @CraigWilson - Yes, that page could stand to mention the `BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention` function. In the absence of any such mention, I thought I needed to add it to a `ConventionPack` just like all the other `FooConvention` objects, and I went down several rabbit trails trying to figure this one out.

Comment: @CraigWilson - Just created https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1465 to track this documentation need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discriminator conventions are separate from class mapping conventions. I'm assuming that your classes A and B derive from a common base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id;
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public int FA;
}

public class B : BaseClass
{
    public int FB;
}
```

I'm also assuming that you want the discriminator field name to be "type" instead of the default of "_t".

You would register a discriminator convention for the base class like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(BaseClass), new ScalarDiscriminatorConvention("type"));
```

You can now serialize and deserialize BaseClass values and the "type" field will contain either "A" or "B" depending on the actual type of the value.

I used the following code to verify the serialized form and to verify that the serialized form could be deserialized:

```
BaseClass a = new A { Id = 1, FA = 1 };
var jsonA = a.ToJson();
var deserializedA = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(jsonA);

BaseClass b = new B { Id = 2, FB = 2 };
var jsonB = b.ToJson();
var deserializedB = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(jsonB);
```

Comment: Thanks. Calling `BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention` on the base class was exactly what I needed. Now that I know what to look for, I can find it in the API documentation, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the reference documentation where I was looking earlier. You helped me a lot!